Bound for Zhandry's result in Quantum random Oracle Model using the inequality of Markov brothers
In the proof of Theorem 3.2 in the paper 'Secure Identity-Based Encryption in the Quantum Random Oracle Model' by Zhandry, the author utilized the inequality by Duffin and Schaffer [DS41] (Markov brothers) to bound the $\Delta$-th derivative of $p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$, where $p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)$ is a degree-$d$ polynomial in $\lambda$ such that $p_{\lambda_0}^{(i)}(0)=0$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, \Delta\}$. Note that $p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)$ lies in the range $[0, 1]$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
$$\left|p_{\lambda_{0}}^{(\Delta)}(\lambda)\right| \le  \frac{4^{\Delta} \Delta !}{2(2 \Delta) !} d^{2 \Delta}$$
Recall Duffin and Schaffer's result: Suppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $|f(x)| \leqq 1$ in the interval $(-1,1)$. W. Markoff gives the best possible bounds for the high derivatives of $f(x)$
$$
\left|f^{(p)}(x)\right| \leqq \frac{n^2\left(n^2-1^2\right) \cdots\left(n^2-(p-1)^2\right)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots(2 p-1)}, \quad-1 \leqq x \leqq 1
$$
This bound is actually attained by the Tchebychef polynomial $T_{\mathrm{n}}(x)=\cos \left(n \cos ^{-1} x\right)$. Duffin and Schaffer [DS41] shown that the condition $|f(x)| \leqq 1$ in the whole interval is unnecessarily restrictive. Instead it is only necessary to assume that $|f(x)| \leqq 1$ at the $n+1$ points $x=\cos (k \pi / n) ; k=0,1,2, \cdots, n$, and the conclusions of Markoffs' theorem are unchanged. These are exactly the points at which $T_n(x)$ attains its maximum in the interval $(-1,1)$.
My question: I attempted to apply the inequality of Duffin and Schaffer for $f(x) = p_{\lambda_0}$, $n=d$, $k=\Delta$ but did not obtain the same result as Zhandry, because Duffin and Schaffer's result applies to the entire interval ([-1,1]), while Zhandry's bound is evaluated over ([0,1]).
\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            \left|p_{\lambda_{0}}^{(\Delta)}(\lambda)\right| &\leq \max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} \left| p_{\lambda_0}^{(k)}(x)\right| \le \max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} \left| p_{\lambda_0}^{(k)}(x)\right|    \\
            & \le \frac{d^2(d^2 - 1^2)(d^2 - 2^2) \cdots (d^2 - (\Delta-1)^2)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2\Delta - 1)} \max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} |p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)| \\
            &\le \frac{(d^2)^{\Delta}(2\cdot 4\cdot 6 \cdots 2\Delta)}{(2\Delta)!}\max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} |p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)| \\
            &= \frac{(d^{2\Delta})2^{\Delta} \Delta!}{(2\Delta)!}\max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} |p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)|   
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
Could you help me explain how Zhandry's bound can be derived?" or "Is there any issue with the bound obtained by Zhandry?"

This is a pure math question. I suggest you delete here and ask at math stack exchange.

If we write $\lambda=(x+1)/2$ and $f(x)=p_{\lambda_0}((x+1)/2)=p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)$, we see that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n=d$ and $|f(x)|\le 1$ in the interval $x\in[-1,1]$ (which is the interval $\lambda\in[0,1]$).
It then follows that
$$\left|\frac{d^\Delta}{dx^\Delta}f(x)\right|=\frac1{2^\Delta}\left|\frac{d^\Delta}{d\lambda^\Delta}p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)\right|.$$
Following your proof we can see that
$$\left|\frac{d^\Delta}{dx^\Delta}f(x)\right|\le\frac{d^{2\Delta}2^\Delta\Delta!}{(2\Delta)!}$$
which tells us that
$$\left|\frac{d^\Delta}{d\lambda^\Delta}p_{\lambda_0}(\lambda)\right|\le2^\Delta\frac{d^{2\Delta}2^\Delta\Delta!}{(2\Delta)!}$$
which is equal to Zhandry's bound.

You're right! By using the method of variable substitution, the inequality can indeed be applied to the interval [0,1], and the term $4^{\Delta}$ in Zhandry's bound can be explained. However, when Zhandry's bound yields $\frac{4^{\Delta} \Delta!}{2(2\Delta)!} d^{2\Delta}$, there is a factor of 2 in the denominator, which, in our assessment, still indicates a discrepancy. What do you think about this factor of 2 in the denominator? Thank you for your support!

@DaiChiDO Apologies, I missed the extra 2. The above is sharp if applied to the Chebyshev polynomial, so the discrepancy could only be accounted for by using the conditions on the derivative, but I cannot see how. OTOH it may be a genuine slip. FWIW, I don't think that it drastically affects any of the subsequent deductions.
